# Cannot run exe file from wpf application

Tags: wpf, process, exe

..and I have no idea why. I can run exe output file from debug folder (application created in wpf), but I cant run file I need to send products into ethernet connected weight.
This exe file reads .plu file (product by product) and adding them into weight memory.

Code im using:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(appPath + "\\Wagi\\" + cbi.Content.ToString() + "\\Kasa1.plu"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("[MT_STAND_FIRE,PLU,WRITE,0,0,0,0]");
                foreach (DataRowView item in prodDG.Items)
                {
                   //write lines about products
                }
                sw.WriteLine("[MT_STAND_FIRE,Extra Text,WRITE,0,0,0,0]");
                sw.WriteLine("[MT_STAND_FIRE,Preset Key,Write,0,0,0,0]");

            }
            string ExecutableFilePath = appPath + @"\Wagi\" + cbi.Content.ToString() + @"\bComScale.exe";

            if (File.Exists(ExecutableFilePath))
            {
                Process.Start(ExecutableFilePath);
            }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you try to run that path in command prompt? When you concatenate path from elements use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

Comment: I've tried to put breakpoint in string ExecutableFilePath, read value and insert text into address bar in explorer - works fine.

Comment: So when you put a breakpoint on `Process.Start(...)` does it execute the command and moves on, hangs, throws an error?

Comment: Theres no errors, after step over just moving down.

Comment: And by the way im 100% sure, that process just doesnt start, becouse bComScale.exe opens progress window and saving logs into 2 files (unfortunately, those logs are empty when running out from wpf app)

Comment: From what you say it seems to execute the command. I would search for problem in the application you run. For example you don't pass any parameters to it so where it searches for input file? Current directory or application directory? Maybe it just does not find input file and quits

Comment: Application im trying to run (that exe file) isnt writed in wpf and i dont have code. It also doesnt need any parameters. Exe file requiers only 2 dll files and 2 configuration files. first config file define weight IP and port. Inside second we define all products to send into weight.

Comment: So in my wpf application im getting product details, save them into kasa1.plu (that works fine), and then all I need is just run exe file. As I said - when I just double click into exe, it imports all products from kasa1.plu. Unfortunately, when Im trying to run file from my app progress window doesnt appear.

Comment: In addition - when I run exe file without ANY of config/dll file, it's write log with error. Thats why (in my opinion) that Process doesnt even start.

Comment: Point still stands. It may be the same issue. Where does the app searches for input/config files or write error file? Current folder or application folder? When you double click on the exe from explorer they are the same but when you run it from another app they may be different. Open command prompt in some random folder, past path and try to execute and see what happens

Comment: Ok, You are right, thanks. When im trying to run file from command prompt it also dosent work. Bad thing is that i dont have any documentation about that file and have no idea what parameters should i put..

Comment: Should be easy to fix. Try [`Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) and, apart from file to execute, provide [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx)

Comment: No problem. I've added an answer to sum up this long thread of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application is executed fine. Problem is in executed application which seems to be looking for a config file in current folder as opposed to application folder. Since these 2 can be differ you need to use different [`Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) overload which allows you to specify [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) for a process.
I would also suggest to use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) when concatenating path from list of elements:

```
string ExecutableFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "Wagi", cbi.Content.ToString(), "bComScale.exe");
```